# Goal conversion rate per page view

Tags: google-analytics

When I go to the "Landing pages" section of Google Analytics (Behaviour > Site Content > Landing pages), I can see "My goal name (Goal 1 Conversion Rate)", which is "The percentage of visits that resulted in a conversion to the goal". This way I know that **XX.XX% of user who landed on a particular page ended up reaching a goal**.

Is there any chance I can retrieve the same data for ANY given page view instead (i.e. know that **XX.XX% of users who viewed a page ended up reaching a goal)**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google Analytics the application and is not programing related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom segment of your users or sessions, who have visited a given page, or have landed on a given page. (Look for Conditions under Advanced group of New segment dialog.) You can filter reports for this segment only, and get the information, you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. That indeed works out for one (or a handful of) page(s), but as a note this requires to configure as many segments as page view there are, so the more pages there are on the site, the more effort. Considering I have 10's of thousands of unique URLs this makes the whole thing impossible.